# What is the relationship between .htaccess and routes.php files in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite, routes

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

And my routes.php file:

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'pages/view';
$route['news/(:any)'] = 'news/view/$1';
$route['news'] = 'news';
$route['(:any)'] = 'pages/view/$1';
```

Don't they basically do the same thing? Which is correct to use?

**Edit: My question is not specific for this example. It is more like, which is good for what? It seems like they both to the same thing? Or am I wrong? **

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The .htaccess file removes the index.php from the URL, whereas the routes.php file controls where the URI segments are pointing to in terms of controllers, actions, and parameters

in other words,

.htaccess is a directive to the apache server to remove index.php from the requested URL, and routes.php just directs your actual php scripts

Comment: possibly. but even if you could, it would not be a good practice to do so

Comment: So what is .htaccess is used for, what is routes.php is used for? I mean in the big picture, not in this specific example.. Which is good for what? It seems like they do the same thing?

Comment: Codeigniter takes all requests through index.php. Everything that follows it is essentially a query string. 'routes.php' parses that query string and points to controllers and actions. htaccess is a directive to the apache server to not show index.php because otherwise it would show up on every page with a variable query string attached.

Comment: The [.htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) is not parsed by the PHP interpreter, which is why it's syntax is probably foreign to you. It's parsed by apache and *can* be responsible for much more than removing the index.php from your URL bar, if you want it to. [`routes.php`](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html) is a one-stop-shop script for redirecting browsers into specific controllers and actions depending on what URL was requested. You can achieve routing with both - I'd put my money on `.htaccess` being faster, but only marginally

Comment: @JordanArseno Thanks, basically then they do the same thing write? And I am assuming routes.php is accessed after .htaccess?

Comment: Yes Koray, on both accounts. However, remember that `routes.php` can only do a small subset of what `.htaccess` is capable of. In the link I provided above, you can read about all the magic `.htaccess` can accomplish. `routes.php` is indeed accessed after `.htaccess`. In fact, `.htaccess` is the FIRST script run, even before `index.php`

Answer (score 1):

The `.htaccess` file tells apache to match any request to a uri that is not a file or folder in the directory that you are serving and forward it to your index.php *controller* (also removing the need to reference `index.php` in the url).

`routes.php` is a map of uris to controllers, and is a codeigniter specific piece of code. The `.htaccess` is independent of your codeigniter code, and can be used independently of any php framework

Comment: So when to use which? For example, should I ( can I ) try skipping the index.php file using the $route array?

Comment: You use both. The `.htaccess` is there in most instances as a _vanity_ thing. To remove `index.php` from routes to the end user. Your CI application would be fully functional without the `.htaccess`. You will always need a single entry point to your codeigniter application (`index.php`), and you need the codeigniter router to match requests handle by apache, to controllers/actions in your application

Comment: Other frameworks like Symfony2 allow you to dump the application routing into a format http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/configuration/apache_router.html for `mod_rewrite` for a performance benefit. However in most simple applications this would not be necessary.